# Too many generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, architecture

I am writing an algorithm for mathematical optimization and am faced with the problem of a large number of generic parameters. There are solutions, problems, operators, and algorithms. Each has its own structure of interfaces so that it could be extended with new classes. Using the example of creating a mutation operator NonUniform in the Main function, I showed the complexity of its creation. This is not a problem if you rarely create such objects, but there are many similar operators and for each, you need to list all the generic parameters, and they are also repeated. I tried to transfer these parameters to methods, but then during inheritance, it is not possible to specify stricter restrictions. How to get rid of so many generics? Maybe it is worth revising the architecture or there are some mechanisms of the language that I do not know.

```
#region Algorithms

interface IAlgorithm<out TProblem, out TSolution>
    where TProblem : IProblem<TSolution>
    where TSolution : ISolution
{
    Random Random { get; }
    TProblem Problem { get; }
    TSolution Best { get; }
}

interface IIterativeAlgorithm<out TProblem, out TSolution>
    : IAlgorithm<TProblem, TSolution>
    where TProblem : IProblem<TSolution>
    where TSolution : ISolution
{
    int CurrentIteration { get; }
}

class IterativeAlgorithm<TProblem, TSolution>
    : IIterativeAlgorithm<TProblem, TSolution>
    where TProblem : IProblem<TSolution>
    where TSolution : ISolution
{
    public Random Random { get; }
    public TProblem Problem { get; }
    public TSolution Best { get; }
    public int CurrentIteration { get; }
}

#endregion

#region Operator

interface IOperator<in TAlgorithm, TProblem, TSolution>
    where TAlgorithm : IAlgorithm<TProblem, TSolution>
    where TProblem : IProblem<TSolution>
    where TSolution : ISolution
{
    public void SetAlgorithm(TAlgorithm algorithm);
}

interface ICoordinateMutator<in TAlgorithm, TFunction, TPoint>
    : IOperator<TAlgorithm, TFunction, TPoint>
    where TAlgorithm : IAlgorithm<TFunction, TPoint>
    where TFunction : IFunction<TPoint>
    where TPoint : IPoint
{
    void MutateCoordinates(TPoint point);
}

abstract class CoordinateMutator<TAlgorithm, TFunction, TPoint>
    : ICoordinateMutator<TAlgorithm, TFunction, TPoint>
    where TAlgorithm : IAlgorithm<TFunction, TPoint>
    where TFunction : IFunction<TPoint>
    where TPoint : IPoint
{
    protected Func<Random> GetRandom { get; set; }

    public CoordinateMutator()
    {
        GetRandom = null;
    }

    public virtual void SetAlgorithm(TAlgorithm algorithm)
    {
        GetRandom = () => algorithm.Random;
    }

    public abstract void MutateCoordinates(TPoint point);
}

class NonUniform<TIterativeAlgorithm, TFunction, TPoint> :
    CoordinateMutator<TIterativeAlgorithm, TFunction, TPoint>
    where TIterativeAlgorithm : IIterativeAlgorithm<TFunction, TPoint>
    where TFunction : IFunction<TPoint>
    where TPoint : IPoint
{
    private Func<int> GetCurrentIteration { get; set; }
    private Func<double[]> GetLowerSearchBorder { get; set; }
    private Func<double[]> GetUpperSearchBorder { get; set; }

    public override void SetAlgorithm(TIterativeAlgorithm algorithm)
    {
        base.SetAlgorithm(algorithm);
        
        GetCurrentIteration = () => algorithm.CurrentIteration;
        GetLowerSearchBorder = () => algorithm.Problem.LowerSearchBorders;
        GetUpperSearchBorder = () => algorithm.Problem.UpperSearchBorders;
    }

    public override void MutateCoordinates(TPoint point)
    {
        Random random = GetRandom();
        double currentIteration = GetCurrentIteration();
        double[] lowerSearchBorders = GetLowerSearchBorder();
        double[] upperSearchBorders = GetUpperSearchBorder();

        throw new NotImplementedException("TODO");
    }
}

#endregion

#region Problems

interface IProblem<in TSolution>
    where TSolution : ISolution
{
}

interface IFunction<in TPoint>
    : IProblem<TPoint>
    where TPoint : IPoint
{
    double[] LowerSearchBorders { get; }
    double[] UpperSearchBorders { get; }
}

abstract class Function<TPoint>
    : IFunction<TPoint>
    where TPoint : IPoint
{
    public double[] LowerSearchBorders { get; }
    public double[] UpperSearchBorders { get; }
}

class Sphere<TPoint>
    : Function<TPoint>
    where TPoint : IPoint
{
    public double GetValueOf(TPoint solution) => throw new NotImplementedException("TODO");
}

#endregion

#region Solutions

interface ISolution
{
}

interface IPoint : ISolution
{
}

class Point : IPoint
{
}

#endregion

private static void Main()
{
    var cm = new NonUniform<IterativeAlgorithm<Function<Point>, Point>, Function<Point>, Point>();
}
```

Comment: If you are finding it hard to follow, then I suggest you break each class into a separate file, and concentrate on one at a time, getting the interface/generics correct, and make sure you write good unit tests.   You are effectively creating a library, and this can seem daunting at first when you have lots to do.

Comment: This code is specially presented in one sheet so that you can understand how the classes are interconnected. I have not yet encountered problems with extending functionality / architecture and interactions between classes. And the problem is that classes, for example NonUniform, are not convenient to create due to the large number of duplicate generics.

Comment: What is the purpose of all the generics? Is it only to allow a `Copy` method returning the correctly typed object? Have you considered other solutions? like using immutability wherever possible, thus avoiding the need for copies. Or just returning a object, and letting the caller cast to the correct type if needed.

Comment: The goal of generics is type safety. That is, use the appropriate classes. For example, in a NonUniform, an operator should use a IIterativeAlgorithm, while other operators of this type could simply use a IAlgorithm. I will remove the ICopy interface from the presented code as it distracts from the problem. Using immutability will not help get rid of duplicate generic arguments when creating an object in a Main method.

Comment: Generics are not needed to ensure type-safety, regular types are sufficient for that. Generics are mostly useful for 1. Containers of various types, 2. Optimization, i.e. the compiler generates code for each specific type, this can improve inlining but can also bloat code size.

Comment: Thanks to the @JonasH, I did not know that the .NET optimizes generics in this way. Maybe I didn’t put it right about type safety. I meant that I used generics so that derived classes would use stricter type constraints than their base classes without interfering with extending the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the main reason why you have too many generics comes from the `ICopy<T>` interface.

You could make it non generic and make the Copy method return an object. Or use the IClonable interface instead.
It would reduce the generic parameters of the other interfaces and classes, but it would require a cast on the result of the Copy method each time its called.

Another option is to use the [Covariant return](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) feature of C# 9 with .NET 5

When an interface inherits ICopy it doesn't have to be generic

```cs
    interface ISolution : ICopy<ISolution>
    {
    }
    interface IPoint : ISolution
    {
    }
```

You need to declare an abstract class implementing the interface :

```cs
    abstract class PointBase : IPoint
    {
        public abstract ISolution Copy();
    }
```

You then can use covariant return to implement the Copy method with a more specific type

```cs
    class Point : PointBase
    {
        public override Point Copy() => new Point();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it helps a little to clean up the code. It is possible to add a Copy method in more specific interfaces / classes. But all the same, to create a Non-uniform operator, you need to specify 3 generic arguments with restrictions and the copy method does not affect this. I will modify the provided code and remove the Copy interface.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the generics are not needed. For example

```
interface ISolution
{
}
```

What is this used for? It has no properties or methods, so I cannot do anything with a solution. The only usage seem to be as a marker, say for dependency injection/reflection, but you do not seem to use it in that way.

Another example is the method

```
public override void MutateCoordinates(TPoint point)
{
    Random random = GetRandom();
    double currentIteration = GetCurrentIteration();
    double[] lowerSearchBorders = GetLowerSearchBorder();
    double[] upperSearchBorders = GetUpperSearchBorder();

    throw new NotImplementedException("TODO");
}
```

We know that point is a `IPoint` that is a `ISolution`. But so what? We cannot use the point for anything since it has no properties or methods, something conveniently left out with the "TODO". We could add properties like `float X {get;} float Y {get;}` to the interface to allow actual usage, but then we could just as well use the method signature

```
public override void MutateCoordinates(IPoint point)
```

A possible reason to use generics is that it might allow for more optimization, at the cost of greater code size. This *might* be relevant for something like a point if you call methods on points million of times, but probably not for higher level concepts like `IAlgorithm`. Profiling and/or benchmarks should show if this is relevant or not. The standard advice is to start of with the simplest solution.

I would consider revising your structure and remove just about all usage of generics with regular types. Creating a good description of a domain like this can be very difficult, and It is difficult to provide good advice without much more information. It is possible generics are the best solution for some kind of modeling. But replacing all types with generic types, as the example seem to show, is probably not the way to go.

Comment: ISolution and IPoint interfaces have properties and methods. I did not specify them and only showed the inheritance hierarchy. The method signature cannot be changed in the way you showed, since this is only one operator that will be embedded in the chain of others that will use other types inherited from IPoint.

Comment: @Boris Melnikov the only restriction on `TPoint` in `MutateCoordinates` is that it is a `IPoint`. Therefore it cannot call any method with any more restrictive generic constraint. Therefore it can be replaced with the interface itself. It might have been different if it needed to return `Something<T>`, but it does not.